# How to split the values from an array using Excel 365

Tags: excel

[image: Extraction]

Left side A, B, C are the fixed values. Full List is the dynamic values.
Any idea how to extract the value from Full List and return all the values on the right?

Comment: Please see [what to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Using `FILTER`:

```
=FILTER($E$2:$E$6,ISNUMBER(XMATCH($E$2:$E$6,A2:A4)))
```

[image]